# How to remove unused MacPorts packages?

Tags: macports

Whenever I install a program via MacPorts, it gets and installs lots of dependencies. When I uninstall said program, how do I make MacPorts recursively remove all unused dependencies with it?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

To avoid accidentally cutting leaves that might be things you requested you should install the `port_cutleaves` package then run `sudo port_cutleaves`
https://guide.macports.org/#using.common-tasks.keeplean

---

[MacPorts 1.9.0 added the `sqlite` `portdbformat`](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-announce/2010-June/000008.html) and [MacPorts 2.0.0 dropped the old `flat` format](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2011-July/024788.html). The `sqlite` port DB format is the default for new installations; old installations that were upgraded to 1.9.x will continue to use the `flat` format<sup>1</sup>. You can convert a 1.9.x `flat` system to the `sqlite` format by upgrading to MacPorts 2.0 or by changing the `portdbformat` value in  `/opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf` and then issuing a *port* command as root (e.g. `sudo port installed`).

One of the features of the new format is that it keeps track of “requested” versus “unrequested” port installations. An unrequested port is one that was only installed because some other port depends on it. The `leaves` pseudo-portname expands to all the unrequested ports upon which no other installed port depends. You can use this to “clean up” unneeded ports even if you did not originally uninstall them with `sudo port uninstall --follow-dependencies portname` (which will do what you want, but only if you remember to use it every time you uninstall something).

---

You should examine your existing leaves before uninstalling any of them.

```
port echo leaves
```

Some common leaves (`automake`, `gperf`, `libtool`, `pkgconfig`) are build-time dependencies of common ports, so you may want to “request” them (`sudo port setrequested port1 port2 port3 …`) to avoid uninstalling them just to have to reinstall them later.

You can uninstall any remaining leaves quite easily:

```
sudo port uninstall leaves
```

---

Note: Before pruning your leaves, you may also want to uninstall old versions of ports that are no longer “active”. This may reveal a few more leaves (i.e. ports that are dependencies of ports that are installed, but inactive):

```
sudo port uninstall inactive
```

---

There are [several sections](http://guide.macports.org/#using.common-tasks.findleaves) in the [MacPorts Guide](http://guide.macports.org/) that also describe the process of using `leaves` to uninstall unneeded ports.

Comment: Thanks. This is quite helpful. It seems that you may have to run echo leaves and uninstall leaves back to back multiple times to make sure that all leaves are cleaned. I ran both commands at least 4 times before echo leaves return empty result

Comment: You could say something like `while sudo port uninstall leaves; do :; done` to automate that.

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen `sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents portname` is incorrect, because `--follow-dependents` will "recursively uninstall all ports that depend on the specified port". The correct option here is `--follow-dependencies`, which will "recursively uninstall all ports that the specified port depended on. This will not uninstall dependencies that are marked as requested or that have other dependents."

Answer (score 10):

[From the docs](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.html#using.port.uninstall):

> The uninstall action will uninstall an
> installed port.
>
> `%% sudo port uninstall vile`
>
> Note: To also recursively uninstall the
> ports that the given port depends on,
> use the `‑‑follow‑dependencies` flag.
> This will not uninstall dependencies
> that are marked as requested or that
> have other dependents.
>
> To recursively uninstall all ports
> that depend on the given port before
> uninstalling the port itself, use the
> `‑‑follow‑dependents` flag.
>
> If a port is a dependency of another
> installed port, uninstall will not
> remove it unless you remove the
> dependent port(s) first. To override
> this behavior, use the `-f` (force)
> switch. This will obviously break the
> dependents. Don't force uninstall
> ports unless you know what you are
> doing.
>
> `%% sudo port -f uninstall vile`

Note the major caveat in the last paragraph. Dependencies are exactly that—dependencies—and different apps can (will) require the same dependencies.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The OP wants to remove a program and the things that it requires, not remove a program and the things that require it.

Comment: @mankoff: `‑‑follow‑dependencies` vs. `‑‑follow‑dependents`; the quoted passage describes both, but only the first applies to the question

Comment: Personally, I think ti is great that Philip explains both parameters, so we are fully aware of the parameters and their implications upon issuing such command

Answer (score 4):

There's also a script in MacPorts' contrib directory called port_cutleaves you can run to remove unneeded dependencies: http://trac.macports.org/browser/contrib/. It'll ask you for each to-be-uninstalled port and allows keeping some, should you want to.

This script is available as a port itself.
`sudo port install port_cutleaves` to install and then `sudo port_cutleaves` to run.

Answer (score 3):

The command to remove a port and its dependents is:

```
sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents foo
```

However, if the port you are uninstalling has dependents it will not uninstall without the `-f` (force) flag.

Of course you should start by reading over the [MacPorts Guide](http://guide.macports.org/) specifically looking into the [Uninstall guide section.](http://guide.macports.org/#using.port.uninstall)

Answer (score 2):

I have written some scripts to automate port cleanup: https://github.com/vasi/macports-tools

The 'macportsfoster' script will output a list of all ports not required by anything in the requested-list, ordered such that 'port deactivate $(macportsfoster)' will remove all of them in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers, and the `--follow-dependents` flag, do not do what you want. If you install `A`, and `A` requires `B`, then thanks to the wonderful package management systems, `B` will be installed for you. You can uninstall `B` and the `--follow-dependents` flag will be aware of and remove `A`. But what if you uninstall `A`, which is more likely, because `A` is what you manually installed in the first place? In this case, `B` is left behind.

If you use fink, the [debfoster](http://www.fruit.je/debfoster/) package is designed to clean out your system and remove unused dependencies.

> Debfoster will help you get rid of
>   packages (libraries for example) get
>   left behind on your system when the
>   program that required it was removed
>   or upgraded to a version that doesn't
>   have the dependency.

While `debfoster` will not work for MacPorts, there appears to be ports of `debfoster`, for example, `portsfoster`, although it seems to be discontinued...

Perhaps no solution currently exists for MacPorts.

Comment: But isn't debfoster for deb files on Debian based system? How do I use it for MacPorts ports on Mac OS X?

Comment: It has been ported to OS X and MacPorts and fink are based on the `apt` system which is used by Debian. I don't use MacPorts, but I did a `fink install debfoster` and it worked just fine for me.

Comment: MacPorts is not related to the `apt` system and does not use `deb` files. The idea of MacPorts is related to FreeBSD ports or NetBSD pkgsrc, but the implementation is very different.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the correction. Regardless, debfoster has been ported to work fine through `fink`. Further searching shows that it **does not** work with MacPorts, but there are clones, for ex, see `portsfoster`

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of `py36-*` packages. As currently Python 3.6 is older, I uninstalled all these packages uninstalling its dependents as:

```
sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents python36
```

I hope it helps